# Why click event not work when I click a image at runtime?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Now I am developing a Firefox extension , and when web page I want to create a image at runtime, now I can show the image , but When I click it to invoke a method , why it is not work? it is my code:

var _img = doc.createElement("img");

_img.setAttribute("id", "floatImage");

_img.setAttribute("src", "abc.jpg");

_img.setAttribute("onclick", "clickimage()");

document.body.append(_img);

function clickimage() 
{
    alert("click");
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an "`onclick`" attribute try adding click [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

```
_img.addEventListener('click', clickimage);
```